# "При входе в личный кабинет" - это же не деепричастный оборот?

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

> Для этого, при входе в личный кабинет, введите емайл, который использовали при регистрации.

Оборот "при входе в личный кабинет" можно заменить на

> войдя в личный кабинет.

Но в данном предложении это не деепричастный оборот, потому что нет деепричастия? Верно?

Answer (score 2):

1. **РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

Возможны варианты:

(1) *Для этого  **при входе в личный кабинет** введите e-mail, который использовали при регистрации.*

Это **обычный** вариант оформления подобных сообщений.

(2) *Для этого, **при входе в личный кабинет**, введите e-mail, который использовали при регистрации.*

Допускается **факультативное** обособление обстоятельственного оборота со значением дополнительного **пояснения** (когда входите в личный кабинет). В этом случае оборот интонационно **подчеркивается**. Но этот вариант используется в том случае, если такое пояснение действительно **нужно.**

2. **ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, одно и то же сообщение можно записать в **трех вариантах:** (1) обстоятельственный оборот, (2) деепричастный оборот, (3) придаточное предложение. Это явление называется **синтаксическая синонимия.**

В каждом случае свои **правила** обособления. Практически всегда обособляется придаточное, обычно обособляется деепричастный оборот, а обстоятельственный оборот обособляется факультативно.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)**

**Примечание**

[Русский орфографический словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB&mode=all&l=1): **имейл**, -а

Специалисты справочно-информационного портала «Русский язык» отмечают, что в «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН это слово зафиксировано как «имейл». При этом латиницей корректно писать **«e-mail».**

Answer (score 0):

1. В вашем предложении нет деепричастного оборота и некоторые поставленные запятые не нужны. Предложение с правильно расставленными знаками препинания будет выглядеть так:

> Для этого при входе в личный кабинет введите емайл, который использовали при регистрации.

2. "При входе в личный кабинет" нельзя заменить на "войдя в личный кабинет", так как это разные времена (настоящее и прошедшее).
   "При входе в личный кабинет" можно заменить на "входя в личный кабинет" — и тогда этот оборот действительно будет обособляться запятыми.